# What device is best to prevent electric motors from burning out?

Tags: electricity, electrical-engineering

Is there any equipment to prevent electric motors from burning out? I have researched about Transient voltage surge suppressor TVSS and also Surge protection device. Can this help?

Comment: Without knowing what phenomenon might cause your motors to "burn out," this question cannot be answered. In as much as you are looking for practical recommendatons: Why don't you ask on electrical engineering what the cause is and what to do about it?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Transient voltage surges are unlikely to hurt any but the tiniest motor. Motors burn out because there is sustained power dissipation in them owing to higher than designed for current. If a motor gets jammed, or its load only lets it spin slowly, the back EMF (which is generated, following Faraday's Law, by the time varying magnetic fluxes through the rotor) becomes small and thus the current large. I've sketched this idea below, where an ideal voltage source imparts a potential difference $V$ across the motor, which, from a circuit standpoint looks like a winding resistance and a voltage source $V_b$. $V_b$ is proportional to the speed of rotation. This phenomenon makes electic motors excellent for traction: the bigger the load, the slower the rotor will spin and the smaller the back EMF. Therefore, the motor naturally draws a higher current $(V-V_b)/R$. The torque is proportional to the current, so the motor can work at a higher rate to cope with the higher load. When starting a train from standstill for example, you get highest torques exactly when you need them - when $V_b=0$.

[image: Back EMF Generation]

All of this can of course go awry: if the motor jams, it will lead to a sustained high current and power dissipation as heat which can literally set it on fire - burn it out.

So the lesson here is : **current sensing and limiting is the way to prevent motor burnout.**